# Can WPF/Silverlight generate a standalone executable?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

Say I want to display an image, with some hot links, rollover, and similar. I know this is fairly easy to do as a webpage, or as a SWF, but I want it to be standalone and not rely on a web browser.  I also want the assets somewhat hidden, just for ease of deployment.

As a SWF my solution is simple.  All the media objects are inside the SWF.

How can I do this with WPF/Silverlight?  I have found that if I use WPF the .net 4 installation can take 20 minutes on some machines. That is totally unacceptable for my uses.   Is there a way to use a subset of WPF that doesn't require that install?

Is there a way to make Silverlight just generate a standalone file like Flash SWF?

Comment: SWFs usually are not standalone either, they require flash, be it via an installation or a player. I think the .NET framework is a bit too huge to make complete standalone applications viable...

Comment: This has been discussed here: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/8691.aspx/1

Comment: I'm ok with relying on the Silverlight plugin as it is a quick/painless download.  However, how do I make a file that people can actually double click as a .xap file is not associated in Windows to open in a browser.  None of the answers so far seem to address this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF runs on top of the .NET platform, your users will have to have this installed to run your application. Silverlight can run as an application out of the browser, but Silverlight runs on top of a separate Silverlight runtime. This is a good bit smaller than the full .NET runtime (about 5MB if I recall) and should be a faster install process (this was one of the original goals).

Comment: Silverlight is a super quick install, so that is ok, but how do I generate a single Silverlight file that someone can just double click to open?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can, with third party tools / frameworks.

I've used [Xenocode postbuild](http://www.xenocode.com/) in the past to embed the .NET framework inside an app and get a single executable that can be run without the .NET framework installed on target PC. Note that Postbuild seems to have been bought out / merged with [Spoon Studio](http://spoon.net/studio/).

For silverlight there's no getting around the need for SL to be installed on the target machine, however there are some very clever tools such as the Dashboard Server from [ComponentArt](http://www.componentart.com/products/ds/) which allow you to deploy Silverlight/Xaml applications to a server but deliver HTML5 to clients across multiple different OS/browsers. In this case you're still going to need an HTML5 compatible browser, but as time goes on this should become more ubiquitous.

Finally, if all you want to do is have a single exe to redistribute (which then relies on .NET Framework at client end) you can use a tool such as [BabelFor.NET](http://www.babelfor.net/) onfuscator, which allows you to merge multiple assemblies into one.

Best regards,

Comment: Silverlight is a super quick install, so that is ok, but how do I generate a single Silverlight file that someone can just double click to open?

Comment: @mrvak Yes, I believe you can, using Offline mode: http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/05/how-to-create-offline-installer-no.html and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/katriend/archive/2009/07/10/silverlight-3-out-of-browser-applications.aspx Just out of interest, what is your requirement that you absolutely cannot deploy .NET?

Answer (score 0):

WPF creates standalone executables when you compile your code. For Silverlight you have to create an out of browser application but it still will need to download the xap file the first time it runs.

Comment: Forgot to mention that for what it refers to images or links you can add them into the resources dictionary and you wont need to give anything more that your exe to the users.

Comment: I think the OP wanted to know if we can embed the .net runtime in the executable itself

Comment: @SteveB, indeed +1 from me :)

Comment: Right, I need to avoid a lengthy install.  Also it turns out that .Net isn't as consistent as I thought, as My first .net4 app won't even display images in WinXP.  So, I'm throwing the idea of WPF out the Window.